# Которого пхп модуля может не хватать на сервера?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Сайт на вордпресе на обычном хостинге... на хостинге пхп 7.2...
Купил сервер, настроил, поставил версию пхп тоже 7.2.... все нормально...
перенес сайт, и некоторые плагины не работают, такие как:
1.Redux Framework,
2. Regenerate Thumbnails,
3. WP All Export Pro,
4. WP Fastest Cache,
5. WPBakery Visual Composer,
6. Yoast SEO Premium,
и другие....
каторого пхп модуля может не хватать?
когда эти плагины отключил - сайт работает...

`2018/05/08 17:09:48 [error] 31610#31610: *100121 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/functions.php on line 259
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy/includes/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 126
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-mapper.php on line 111
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cart_url in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy/header-default.php on line 56
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cart_url in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy/header-default.php on line 76
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/p
2018/05/08 17:09:48 [error] 31610#31610: *100121 FastCGI sent in stderr: "mes/savoy-child/functions.php on line 259
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/functions.php on line 259
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/functions.php on line 259
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy-child/functions.php on line 259
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::add_pagination() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Iconic_WSP_Pagination_Below_3_2_4::loop_end() should not be called statically in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 600
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method 
2018/05/08 17:09:48 [error] 31610#31610: *100121 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.170.192.70, server: newtest.staff-clothes.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "newtest.site", referrer: "http://newtest.site/"
2018/05/08 17:09:49 [error] 31610#31610: *100163 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/themes/savoy/includes/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 126
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /home/wordpress/www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-mapper.php on line 111
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/wordpress/www/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208" while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.170.192.70, server: newtest.site, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "newtest.staff-clothes.com", referrer: "http://newtest.site/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s"`

Comment: дак логи то посмотреть можно какие-нить? такие ошибки должны логгироваться. хотя это вордпресс..

Comment: в логах nginx - ничего толком нет
в пхп логах - все тоже ...
то пытаюсь найти что-то общее в этих планинах...

Comment: А что значит не работает? Если возникает какая-то ошибка, то информаци об этом должна быть в логах. Приложите логи и вам помогут, потом что экстрасенсов здесь нет.

Comment: Викинул логи, а ошыбка 502...
админка работает...
и работает сайт, когда юзер залогинен, а 502 ошыбка с анонимного окна

Comment: Вы сами почитайте, что выложили. Там сплошные deprecated и notice, это ни о чем. Найдите то место в логе, где fatal.

Comment: @teran чем логирование php отличается в WordPress? Я вам открою страшную тайну - ничем.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я не высокого мнения о качестве кода плагинов вордпресса, так что уровень логгирования ошибок вряд ли там высок. понятное дело, что пхп-варнинги, нотисы, и ерроры логгируеются не зависимо от платформы, но я не об этом. так что ничего нового вы мне открыли.

Comment: @teran качество кода к логированию не имеет никакого отношения вообще. Так что ничего нового, кроме личного неприятия WordPress, вы тут не высказали

Comment: @KAGGDesign да что вы говорите. качественный код, в моем понимании, обрабатывает ошибки и записывает их куда надо, или иными способами информирует разработчика. Ошибка в модуле не должна приводить к крашу системы в целом. Если плагин требует какого-то специфического модуля пхп, то он должен выполнить проверку, и в случае чего не должен запускаться. у вас видимо, каике то другие представления о качественном коде.

Comment: @teran все, что вы тут написали, не имеет отношения к WordPress вообще и к логированию php тоже. Логи php - более низкий уровень, чем cms или framework. Так что ваш первый возглас "такие ошибки должны логироваться, хотя это вордпресс", так и остаётся ни о чем. Что в bitrix, что в laravel, или что там вам нравится, логирование php работает одинаково. И если кодер идиот, то он и в laravel не спросит, установлен ли mb_string, к примеру. Так что laravel, yii2, WordPress - все едино. Php он в Африке php.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вот про то и речь, что будучи весьма распространенной платформой вордпресс имеет огромное число низкокачственных плагинов, которые пишут кодеры-идиоты. Так что моя ремарка про вордпресс направлена была исключительно на этот факт. вы же почему то все пытаетесь увести тему в сторону того как пхп свои ошибки в лог пишет. я уже сказал, что речь не об этом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77225/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-teran).